# The Constructor RemoteWebDriver(URL, DesiredCapabilities) is undeifned

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

Multiple markers at this line 
- The Constructor RemoteWebDriver(URL, DesiredCapabilities) is undeifned
- The Constructor URL(String) is undefined

'
        package GridLearnings;

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.URL;

public class GridSample  {

    @Test
    public void TestLogin()
    {
        DesiredCapabilities cap= DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        cap.setBrowserName("Chrome");
        cap.setPlatform(Platform.ANY);

        RemoteWebDriver d =new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"),cap);



    }

}
```

'

Comment: Do you think we are getting complete context of what have you trying to do? what is expected? what is happening? Please read  [mcve] and edit your question accordingly and follow same in next post hence forth

Answer (score 3):

`RemoteWebDriver` accepts an `URL` as a parameter, but the URL from `java.net` package.

Change 
`import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.URL;`

to: `import java.net.URL`